# Hibernate delete and insert primary key

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have table in following structure:

```
CustomerId 
PaymentDate 
PK (CustomerId+PaymentDate)
```

System insert a soft date called as PaymetnDate which reflects the date where payment need to be done.

Sometime due to downtime PaymentDate system is not able to reach and paymentDate need to updated once payment is done.

For this we are doing:

//Note there is only single row for each customer. PaymentDate in primaryKey is due to legacy. Which we are planning to remove.

```
function deleteAndInsert
        final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ClassName.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(CUSTOMER_ID, customerId));
        final ClassName result = (ClassName) criteria.uniqueResult();

        if(result != null) {
            session.delete(result);
        }
        session.save(newObject);
        session.flush();
        session.evict(ClassName)
```

It works perfect if deleteAndInsert called once. 
It is not working if function is getting called **twice** in short time of period. What could be the problem?

Second call of function get primary key error. Which automatically get resolved in retry.

I am thinking that result caching is causing the issue. But not sure

Comment: Maybe is the cache. Add .setCacheble(false) to the criteria.